# Laravel 5 Many to Many insert Custom Pivot Cell

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find any on the official doc.

I need to insert `$product_count` in my `invoice_product` pivot table

```
 $product_ids = [1,2,3]; 
 $product_count = [1,1,1];

 $invoice->product()->attach($product_ids, $product_count); // don't work
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `invoice_product` (`0`, `created_at`, `invoice_id`, `product_id`, `updated_at`, `1`) values (2, 2016-04-26 15:33:57, 437, 1500125, 2016-04-26 15:33:57, 1), (2, 2016-04-26 15:33:57, 437, 5121100, 2016-04-26 15:33:57, 1))

It is expecting a string in the 2nd arg, how should I go about it.

```
 $product_ids = [1,2,3]; 
 $product_count = [array('product_count'=>2), array('product_count'=>3), array('product_count'=>4)];

 $invoice->product()->attach($product_ids, $product_count); // don't work
```

> preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

UPDATE so when i tried

```
$invoice->product()->attach($product_ids, array('product_count'=>2));
```

this will put the static 2 in all of the invoice_product, how do I insert it as array b/c each product count need to be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your database field is : `count`

**invoice_product table**

```
invoice_id
product_id
count
```

**Product Model**

```
public function invoices() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Invoice')->withPivot('count');
}
```

**Invoice Model**

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('count');
}
```

**In your controller**

```
//$invoice->products()->attach([1 => ['count' => 1]]);
```

In general cases, you must attach :

```
[
$productId1 => ['count' => $countId1],
$productId2 => ['count' => $countId2],
]
```

In your case, you have to do something like :

```
$product_ids = [1,2,3]; 
$product_count = [1,1,1];

$attachements = [];
foreach ($product_ids as $index => $productId) {
    $attachements[$productId] = ['count' => $product_count[$index]];
}

$invoice->products()->attach($attachements);
```

Answer (score 0):

so, apparently I need to make the 1st arg as an associative array matching the col name,

```
    $product_ids = [];
    $product_count = [];
    foreach($products as $product) {
        array_push($product_ids, array('product_id'=>$product->id, 'product_count'=>$product->product_count));
    }

    $invoice->product()->attach($product_ids);
```